Using __getattr__ with SQLAlchemy ORM leads to RecursionError
Simple self-contained example below, presupposing SQLite.
I'm using the SQLAlchemy (v1.3) ORM, where I have a table of world-given whatsits that should not be changed. I also have another table with the same whatsits, in a form more usable to the developer. For instance, this table of dev-whatsits has fields to keep cached results of complex calculations made on data in the raw whatsits. The dev-whatsits table is connected to the raw-whatsits table through its ID as a foreign key; this is also modelled as a (one-way) relationship in SQLAlchemy.
This works fine. Now, frequently while interacting with a dev-whatsit, the developer will want to look at attributes in the underlying raw version. This is simple enough:
result = dev_instance.raw_whatsit.some_attribute

However, since it's the same real-world object that is represented, it would be more convenient and intuitive to be able to skip the middle bit and write:
result = dev_instance.some_attribute

I thought this would be reasonably simple using __getattr__, e.g. like this:
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            getattr(self.raw_whatsit, item)
        except AttributeError as e:
            # possibly notify here?
            raise e

However, this leads to a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded after going back and forth between the getattr here and the line return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_) in InstrumentedAttribute.__get__ in sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py.
Is there a better way of "redirecting" attribute access in the way I want? Or is there a simple fix I have not yet found?
Self-contained code giving RecursionError follows. Comment out AppWhatsit.__getattr__ and the very last print statement to make it work.
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class RawWhatsit(Base):
    '''Data for whatsit objects given by the world, with lots and lots of attributes.
    This table should not be changed in any way.'''
    __tablename__ = 'raw_whatsits'

    whatsit_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    one_of_many_attributes = Column(Integer)
    another_attribute = Column(String(16))

    def __init__(self, wid, attr, attr2):
        '''Just a helper for this demonstration.'''
        self.whatsit_id, self.one_of_many_attributes, self.another_attribute = wid, attr, attr2

class AppWhatsit(Base):
    '''A model of a whatsit intended to be used by the developer.
    It has a separate db table and, for instance, caches results of lengthy calculations.
    Has foreign key back to corresponding raw whatsit.'''
    __tablename__ = 'app_whatsits'

    whatsit_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('raw_whatsits.whatsit_id'), primary_key=True)
    result_of_complex_calc = Column(Integer)

    raw_whatsit = relationship('RawWhatsit')

    def __init__(self, raw_instance):
        self.whatsit_id = raw_instance.whatsit_id

    def do_complex_calc(self):
        self.result_of_complex_calc = (self.raw_whatsit.one_of_many_attributes +
                                       len(self.raw_whatsit.another_attribute))

    # Attempt at making attributes of the raw whatsits more easily accessible. Leads to bottomless recursion.
    # (Comment out this and the very last print statement below, and the code works.)
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            getattr(self.raw_whatsit, item)
        except AttributeError as e:
            # possibly notify here?
            raise e

def run():
    # Set up database stuff:
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))  # a class
    session = Session()

    # Populate raw table (in reality, this table is given by the world):
    raw_instance = RawWhatsit(1, 223, 'hello')
    session.add(raw_instance)
    session.commit()
    print(session.query(RawWhatsit).first().__dict__) # ... 'whatsit_id': 1, 'one_of_many_attributes': 223, ...

    # Later: Create a developer-friendly whatsit object associated with the raw one:
    raw_instance_from_db = session.query(RawWhatsit).first()
    dev_instance = AppWhatsit(raw_instance_from_db)
    session.add(dev_instance)
    session.commit()
    dev_instance.do_complex_calc()
    print(session.query(AppWhatsit).first().__dict__)   # ... 'result_of_complex_calc': 228, 'whatsit_id': 1, ...

    # All is good. Now I want to see some of the basic data:
    print(dev_instance.raw_whatsit.another_attribute)   # hello
    # ...but I'd prefer to be able to write:
    print(dev_instance.another_attribute)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()


SQLAlchemy keeps the session state of an instance in the _sa_instance_state attribute, which is set on an instance if the instance doesn't yet have one. To test if an instance has the attribute, however, it has to call __getattr__ of the instance to query the name _sa_instance_state, so your overridden __getattr__ should raise an AttributeError in this case to allow the initialization logics to instantiate a state object for the instance:
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item == '_sa_instance_state':
        raise AttributeError
    return getattr(self.raw_whatsit, item)

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/AwareMerryPatches

Right! I did come across '_sa_instance_state' while rummaging about with the debugger, but couldn't fathom what it was for, what to do with it, nor whether there were further such magical attribute names. This is exactly what I was looking for; thanks!
